# Trying to build on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build my app but i received this error. I have rebuilt, cleaned progect and reset Android Studio. This is the screenshot of the problem: [image]

Code error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\User-1.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\49c100caf72d658aca8e58bd74a4ba90fa2b0d70\stax-api-1.0.1.jar' to 'C:\Users\User-1\Documents\workspace\WebUpHosting\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\stax-api-1.0.1_4deeb811af0ea67608aa694ead937d7c9ac36202'

The problem is when i am building, because my app compiles right. Anyone knows how i could solve that?

UPDATE:

buil.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.webuphosting.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0"


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell the exact problem with more code to see, but as a solution, you could just simply disable pre-dex:

> boolean preDexLibraries
>
> Whether to pre-dex libraries. This can improve incremental builds, but clean builds may be slower.

To do so, add the following block in your main module (app)'s `build.gradle` file, inside the `android`:

```
android {
  // everything else
  dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
  }
}
```

By default, it is set to **true**, so by setting it to **false**, you could get around your issue, but it may not solve the root-cause.

Comment: Let us know if we need to investigate further, and if so, please provide your full `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I have added the buld.gradle to my question

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your gradle cache instead? You can do so by deleting the folder under `~/.gradle/caches` and then using the Android Studio command `Build > Rebuild Project`.

Comment: SOLVED: I have added Java 8 and suddenly works well.

Comment: @KikeRodriguez Glad to hear it! It could have happened that you may have introduced a new dependency that suddenly required it? Or just a import statement on top of one of your class? That is why it is a good idea to compile often, so you catch it closest to the source! Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, i have introduced new depencies. I think that it was the problems. Thanks to everyone